# Network area (lost content)

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Usually i have size/content to show you what the size of the uncompressed data when your response is getting compressed. I have seemed to have lost this on one computer. I just have "size". Does anyone know how to get this back without having to try to reinstall chrome (i have the latest version of google chrome for windows (37.0.2062.120 m (64-bit))

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have activated the compact view by clicking on the "Use small resource rows" icon.
Click on the "Use large resource rows" icon to toggle this setting (the fourth icon in the top-left corner).

[image]

#### Small resource rows

[image]

#### Large resource rows

[image]

Next time, when you get stuck with an unwanted devtools setting, you could also open the options of the devtools (gear icon), scroll down at the General tab and click on the "Restore defaults and reload" button to reset all devtools settings to their default values.

Comment: thanks so much. You saved me a re install. I guess i accidentally clicked that button.